# On the Limit of a quotient $\frac{2^n}{e^{P(n)}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $m$ be a fixed natural number and suppose that $P_m$ is a polynomial with rational coeficients(in other words $P_m(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^ma_ix^i$ where  $a_i, 0\leq i\leq m$ are rational numbers).

Prove that $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n}{e^{P(n)}}=0\text{ or }\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{P(n)}}{2^n}=0.$$
I know that $ln 2$ is an irrational number but I cannot use it here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $P(n)=n\ln 2$ then the limit is $1$, but $\ln2\notin\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I am aware of this.  But it doesnt seem to help.  Remember  the equality is in the limit sense.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $m=1,$ and $P_1(x) = qx,$ with $q$ a positive rational. Then

$$\frac{2^n}{P_1(n)} = \frac{2^n}{e^{qn}} = \left (\frac{2}{e^{q}}\right)^n.$$

Could $2/e^q=1?$ No, because $e$ is transcendental.

Comment: The case of polynomial of degree 1 can easily be established. Here it is easy to write as a quotient raised to power of n. But for general polynomial of degree n, it is not easy to do that. Besides a sequence of rational numbers can converge to an irrational number.

Comment: That rationals can converge to an irrational is not relevant. Since $2/e^q\ne 1, $it is either $<1$ or $>1,$ and the result follows.